# if para un REQUEST con php

Tags: php, html, formularios, checkbox

Estoy tratando de enviar un request dependiendo una condicion en mi caso utilizo un input type=checkbox.
Necesito que si el checkbox está seleccionado, envie "request 1 pero sino esta seleccionado envie "request 2".

¿Cómo debo formular el if en PHP si los atributos de mi input son los siguientes?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="request1" value="enviar" id="seleccionado">
```

Comment: Creo que el valor enviado sería `enviar` en este caso, para que envíes `request1` como valor, tendrías que poner ` value="request1"`.

Comment: Ok supongamos que el request1 se enviara cuando el checkbox esta seleccionado. y que value="request1"
entonces mi if en php seria algo como
$ENVIAR="request1"

if($ENVIAR==true){
............

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debo aclarar que se puede hacer fácilmente con PHP, comprobando si la variable está definida o no en los datos que se reciben del formulario, y de no ser así, utilizar un valor por defecto:

```
$campo1 = "request2";
if (isset($_POST["request1"])) { // asumiendo que se haya enviado en un post
    $campo1 = "request1";
}
```

O en una sola línea:

```
$campo1 = isset($_POST["request1"]) ? "request1" : "request2;
```

---

Personalmente prefiero la solución que muestro a continuación:

Este es un pequeño truco que no tiene que ver con PHP, pero que siempre me ha parecido útil al momento de querer enviar un valor «por defecto» en estos casos, consiste en utilizar un campo oculto con el valor respectivo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="campo1" value="request2">
<input type="checkbox" name="campo1" value="request1" id="seleccionado">
```

De esta forma, si el checkbox no está seleccionado, se recibirá `campo1="request2"`.

Comment: Aunque cabe decir que si los valores se manipulasen vía JS  para luego enviarlos vía Ajax no tendría sentido tener un `input` oculto solamente para esto. Yo hasta prefiero resolverlo del lado de PHP, como haces con el ternario.

Comment: Es verdad, de hecho podrían hasta enviar un formulario totalmente distinto y un montón de cosas más.